# MS Excel: "The file format differs from the format that the file name extension specifies"

Tags: windows, excel, csv, openoffice.org

I'm generating some CSV files from a ICEfaces application, simply writing on the HttpServletResponse.

All these files are correctly opened by OpenOffice, one of them can be opened by OpenOffice but not in Microsoft Excel. The error message is "The file format differs from the format that the file name extension specifies". If I try to go on it stops on row 106 saying "Unable to read row 106".

The file is named "blacklist.csv", the content type is "text/csv". Here's an excerpt of the file content:

```
ID;CodiceStazione;NomeStazione;Sensore;Inizio;Fine
49;"PU59";"Nipozzano";"LW";"2012-01-01 00:00";""
158;"PI01102365";"Belvedere";"AT";"2013-01-01 00:00";""
159;"PI01102365";"Belvedere";"LW";"2013-01-01 00:00";""
...
1439;"RP010";"Castelnuovo Scrivia";"RR";"2015-07-20 00:00";""
```

The last row is row 106, but is seems to me it is similar to the other rows.

Any suggestion?

Comment: That file is delimited by `;`, and a csv file is supposed to be delimited by comma (`,`). OpenOffice/LibreOffice is more lenient about this.

Comment: Semicolon conforms to the Italian settings.
I solved by putting the headers in the first line in double quotes, i.e.:

"ID";"CodiceStazione";"NomeStazione";"Sensore";"Inizio";"Fine"

Comment: Had this happen to me with non-printable characters "finding" their way into the data (user input in my case). Have you looked into line 106 with a good text editor (like Notepad++ with _Show All Characters_ `on`)?

Comment: Yes. I also tried to remove line 106 and all lines except the first three but the problem was still there. It was the missing double quotes in the first line that made Excel unhappy. Microsoft error messages are misleading as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Excel uses regional settings of the used operation system to open csv files. It depends on your system how to change it. Have a look here: https://superuser.com/questions/476327/how-do-i-save-an-excel-spreadsheet-as-a-semi-colon-separated-values-file